# In Rails REST, how to configure a second parameter for a third level parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following structure of menus that have items that can have notes. I'd like to create an endpoint of menus with items that only have notes so....

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :notes
   belongs_to :menu
end
class Note  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

I have set up associated resourdes in my routes.rb file but what if I want want menus with items that only have notes. Would a nested route be reccomeneded or something else? I would probably do something like:

```
resources :menus
get '/menus/:menu_id/only_items_with_notes' => 'menus#only_items_with_notes'
```

Since we are going two levels down (and nesting seems frowned upon beneath a first level) but not sure if this would be recommended. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Only add another parameters one after another

```
get '/menu/:menu_id/:other_parameter/only_items_with_notes' => 'menus#only_items_with_notes'
```

regards!

Comment: thx - I tihnk I might have mis-phrased question. I am not adding another params. only_items_with_notes is essentially a BOOL with a value set to 0 - I guess I'm not sure if making it a nested resource makes sense. Perhaps, I'm not fulling getting your answer. thx